# Debugging application on startup

Tags: c++, qt, crash, startup

The 64 bit Qt-Gui application I authored, crashes when attempting to launch from visual studio with the message:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.

There is no compilation error. The application crashes as it attempts to load all the Debug-symbols, DLLs and lib's.

Any pointers for debugging in such a scenario ?

Comment: Download and run the tool from http://www.dependencywalker.com  This is an updated version of the depends.exe tool included with the Windows SDK.

Comment: @Kyle I have added try catch block right in the main method, the application control does not even reach there before the crash :(

Comment: @BenVoigt That did it !! Upon verification, I found I was linking to a third party 32-bit libraries. Changing it to its 64 bit counterpart did the trick. Thanks !! Please post it as an answer, I will mark it as one.

Comment: @Vishnu: I have done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message typically means that while the loader was processing dependencies, one of the dependent DLLs could not be loaded (not found, corrupted file, incompatible, problem with one of its own dependencies, `DllMain` returned false).

A tool that's very helpful for tracking down dependency problems is Dependency Walker (`depends.exe`).  It's included in the Windows SDK from Microsoft, but you should visit http://www.dependencywalker.com and download the latest version.